# undefined reference to __b64_ntop: tmux compilation error on centOS

Tags: tmux

I've got tmux at http://tmux.sourceforge.net/. And I've read README carefully, installed all dependencies( libevent, ncurses-dev...). But when I ran "make" command, it showed an error like the following:

> .../tty.c:1067: undefined reference to `__b64_ntop'

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open the `Makefile`, find this line:

`LIBS = -lutil -lcurses -levent -lrt`

change it to this:

`LIBS = -lutil -lcurses -levent -lrt -lresolv`

it will work. Lack of the `libresolv` resulting your error, no `e` trailing the word, not `resolve`.

when you launch tmux, if exists error like this:

```
tmux: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

you need a soft link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5 /usr/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `LIBS=` line for the top-level `Makefile`, adding `-lresolve` at the end and then run `make` again.

This worked for me on a CentOS 6 system (after following the advice [here](https://superuser.com/a/738830) for installing a newer `libevent` from source).

Source: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/1696